# problem installing apache2.2-common on my Trusty

Tags: apt

I think I need to install `apache2.2-common` on my server Ubuntu trusty 14.04. But when I try I get a error message:

```
apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2 (>= 2.3~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now, I am on this versions :

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

# apache2ctl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04

# uname -a
Linux evx2403105 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# apt-cache policy apache2.2-common

apache2.2-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1~ubuntu14.04.2
  Version table:
     2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1~ubuntu14.04.2 0
        100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
```

From that, the message tell me `apache2 (>= 2.3~)` but precisely I am on a version 2.4.7 for Apache. So, unless I misunderstood the error message, It should be ok. And my packages Apache seems well installed:

```
# dpkg -l | grep apache2    
ii  apache2                          2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13                   amd64        Apache HTTP Server    
ii  apache2-bin                      2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13                   amd64        Apache HTTP Server (binary files and modules)    
ii  apache2-data                     2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13                   all          Apache HTTP Server (common files)    
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork              2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13                   amd64        transitional prefork MPM package for apache2    
ii  apache2-utils                    2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13                   amd64        Apache HTTP Server (utility programs for web servers)    
ii  libapache2-mod-php5              5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.20              amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)    
ii  libapache2-mod-suphp             0.7.2-0ubuntu1                      amd64        Apache2 module to run PHP scripts with the owner permissions
```

Can anybody help me to understand the problem and fix it?

Comment: Why do you need to install 2.2?

Comment: Hello. First : thanks for your answer. And second, to answer you : well I searched another version but... Mayby I didn't seen it. There is no apache2.4-common, at least. Do you know the good package's name ? I have nothing against the fact to install a more recent. In fact, I thought just - for multiple reason - it was this one I have to install.

Comment: In fact, it's even the only package I found, by my sources.list : # apt-cache policy apache2* | grep common
apache2.2-common:

Comment: The question remains, why are you trying to install 2.2-common....  Did something prompt you that you needed that package?  Does Apache not work properly?  Are you trying to install a module that requires 2.2-common?

Comment: Ah, ok. I explain you the context. First, I already configured a server apache, but not completly, and only for myself, so I am not specialised in this job. And overall, I don't know very well the service. Just enough to install it and understand, globally what I do. From that apologize if I ask some questions wich could seems non-sense for you.

Comment: Now, for my company I must dupplicate a configuration to migrate some web servers on a new server, to stop the old one. But of course, the original one is an old server.

Comment: So, naturally, versions changed. It's possible, for example, that the package "common" is nomore useful for my new configuration, as the version of Apache2 is different. I am not sure about that. What I know is : on the old server, there is this package.

Comment: So, as I will have to configure the new server according what it was done on the old one, I thought I have to install the package in question. If you tell me the package is nomore useful for my version of Apache, that's ok.

Comment: If you tell me that what I try to do is non-sense, I would accept that. If you tell me there is an equivalent with my new version, well, I let you tell me wich one (as I didn't find it :)). I am sure of nothing, for now. I searched on internet, of course, but I didn't yet find definitive answer. It's why I need help, as you can see :) I hope it answer to your question. If it's not the case, don't hesite to tell me. I am open :)

Comment: You don't need it.  What you're finding is a backport.  I understand trying to make things equal, however, sometimes things are deprecated.  Your installation of 2.4.7 should be whole and working properly.  If you run into an issue, post that issue and you'll get help.  FYI, I run a web cluster using 2.4.18, and I don't have *-common installed.  :)  For future reference, 'less is more' when it comes to installing.  Only install something when it's needed directly.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot !!! :) I will see what I will obtain. And I will tell you. :)  Happy to read you. Have a nice day!d